facing issue with using onload on aws server
Some of my applications seem to work with onload and some are not working.
(not working)
[infra@ts-binance-psr01 binance_combinedmd]$ sudo -E onload --profile=latency ping google.com
onload: Turning huge pages off because the stack is going to be used by multiple users
oo:ping[19493]: netif_tcp_helper_alloc_u: ERROR: Failed to allocate stack (rc=-16)
See kernel messages in dmesg or /var/log/syslog for more details of this failure
dmesg here
[102439.097934] [onload] [7]: WARNING: huge pages are incompatible with AF_XDP. Disabling hugepage support.
[102439.179934] [sfc efhw] af_xdp_flush_rx_dma_channel: FIXME AF_XDP
[102439.183378] [sfc efhw] af_xdp_flush_tx_dma_channel: FIXME AF_XDP
(working)
sudo -E onload --profile=latency bin/binance_combinedmd config/binance_combinedmd.cfg
oo:binancecombinedm[19430]: Using Onload 20220803 [2,TSTACK]
oo:binancecombinedm[19430]: Copyright 2019-2022 Xilinx, 2006-2019 Solarflare Communications, 2002-2005 Level 5 Networks
Does anybody has any idea what is wrong here? this is onload installation on an aws server.
